# undefined method `aasm_state' in aasm gem related issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 3.2.22.
I have problem regarding aasm gem.
When I'm checking the aasm state on particular object I'm getting error

For example `if @advisor.suspended?`, where `advisor` is object and state is `suspended`, I'm getting error as:

```
undefined method `aasm_state' for #<Advisor:0x000000060da8f8>
```

please reply if anybody has faced the same issue.

Comment: Did you add `aasm_state` column into your `advisors` table?

Comment: It's either a compatibility problem with Rails 3.2, or you've not got the `aasm_state` column in your datatable.

Comment: https://github.com/aasm/aasm/issues/234